# Android - Using custom ActionBar

Tags: android

I have a custom `ActionBar` layout which I want to use in almost all of my `Activities`.

The problem is the text doesn't appear.

This is how I use it in an `Activity`

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_theme);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Signup");
```

But the title "Signup" doesn't appear on the `ActionBar`..

The theme of the `ActionBar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_theme_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does this mean that I can't just do `setTitle("asdf")`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default `setTitle` method is incompatible with a custom view. It's either one or the other.

Comment: Why not just use Toolbar?

Comment: Yes, this is mainly because you are using a custom layout. If you want the basic features like `setTitle()` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` then I suggest you should avoid using custom layout.

Comment: @gjnidea Toolbar? Is that the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` thingy? @SMR How to set the title in the center??

Comment: @KevinMurvie yes. I strongly suggest you study material design first, it won't take much time and if you learn it, it will save you a lot of time. https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: @gjnidea Yes I will, I am installing the app to my phone as I type.. One thing though, is it possible to use the Toolbar like layout? Like.. I can put `TextView` inside it or only basic coloring and alignment?

Comment: @KevinMurvie if I'm not mistaken, it is possible, also, there is the [AppBarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) which extends LinearLayout for more complex toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you can use toolbar as ActionBar and that toolbar can have any custom layout you wish. Here is the reference [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Declare this in activity xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

Then in java code use

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

for this to work perfectly your Activity should extends [AppCompatActivit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Comment: In the xml? As in every xml for every activity or..?

Comment: you can create seperate xml then include it in all activities xml ousing layout tag, but yes should be present in every activity xml tree

Comment: Is there a solution in which I can just call `ActionBar` in every Java class? And use a custom XML layout for it?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm going to use this anyway.. So basically every of my `Activity` which uses the bar must have `extends AppCompatActivity`? And what about the theme in manifest? Should it still be styled thru there or use default theme because it will be overriden anyway, or what?

Comment: @KevinMurvie i have updated answer for styles.xml please check now

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction and I picked up many interesting info around on how to use the Toolbar, thanks! The style I'm using is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` though, I use the `Toolbar` to contain my `TextView` :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. If you set a custom layout to your action bar, you need to change the textview of it like if it was a normal view.

If you are using this layout several time, keep a reference of your action bar or of the viewgroup.

```
ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your layout containing your text view,null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

(TextView)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_theme_title).setText(...)
```