# Android - getActionBar() null reference

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm following this [Androidhive tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) for sliding menu using `DrawerLayout`

I've tried using their code to make a new project and it works, BUT! When I tried applying it into my actual class, it doesn't work......... It returns `null` value. I used it like..

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
...
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I used the theme :

```
<style name="AppThemeWithAction" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/miBlue</item>
    </style>
```

I've researched that it might be because of I have no `TitleBar`, but it doesn't seem to be that way..

If I have missed any essential info to solve the problem, please do comment

UPDATE :

I am trying not to modify the source like changing the `ActionBar` into `Toolbar` because I might ruin something else in process lol.

So.. My question now is.. Is every method on `ActionBar` can be used for `Toolbar`? Is there any equivalent for the former bar to the latter bar??

For example :

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Will changing into `Toolbar` cause compatibility issues to Kitkat and below though?

Comment: same question again and again refer this link
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Extend your activity as `AppCompatActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar`

Comment: @Clairvoyant  i already answered that here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851668/android-using-custom-actionbar/34851922#34851922

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AppCompat you always have to call `getSupportActionBar()` no matter which Android Version your App is running.

```
ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
```

I would advise you to use the new `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`, because it's way more flexible to use.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to extend your Activity as

```
public yourActivityName extends AppCompatActivity
```

And then use

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Import `ActionBar` as support v7